# C++17 if constexpr() usage with tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

I am using VS2017 with C++17 support enabled.

I want to try to make a "Transformer" class that when provided with a certain type which is supported it will transform the type, otherwise it will return the variable as is. The goal is to pass all variable types to the transformer, and "hide" which ones its transforming. This way callers can try to transform everything and don't need to worry about whether or not transforming is necessary, the transformer will know.

A more complete example (edited from original):

```
    class MyPoint
{
public:
    int x = 0;
};

class NotMyPoint
{
public:
    int x = 50;
};

template <typename T>
class ITransform
{
    public:

    virtual ~ITransform() {};

    virtual T InTransform(const T &in) const = 0;

    virtual T OutTransform(const T &out) const = 0;

    //Check if the argument type is the same as this class type
    template <typename X>
    constexpr bool CanTransform() const
    {
        return std::is_same<X, T>::value;
    }
};

class MyTransformer :
    public ITransform<MyPoint>
{
public:
    MyTransformer() = default;

    virtual MyPoint InTransform(const MyPoint &in) const override
    {
        auto newPt = in;
        newPt.x += 100;
        return newPt;
    }

    virtual MyPoint OutTransform(const MyPoint &in) const override
    {
        auto newPt = in;
        newPt.x -= 100;
        return newPt;
    }
};

template <class... TRANSFORMERS>
struct VariadicTransformer
{
    constexpr VariadicTransformer() = default;

    /** \brief parse using validateParse but catch throw */
    template <typename T>
    inline T Transform(const T& in)
    {
        return TransformImpl<sizeof...(TRANSFORMERS)-1, T>(in);
    }

private:
    /// last attempt to find matching transformer at I==0, if it fails return the original value
    template<std::size_t I = 0, typename T>
    inline typename std::enable_if<I == 0, T>::type TransformImpl(const T &in) const
    {
        if (std::get<I>(transformers).CanTransform<T>())
            return std::get<I>(transformers).InTransform(in);
        else
            return in;
    }

    /// attempt to find transformer for this type
    template<std::size_t I = 0, typename T>
    inline typename std::enable_if < I != 0, T>::type TransformImpl(const T &in) const
    {
        if (std::get<I>(transformers).CanTransform<T>())
            return std::get<I>(transformers).InTransform(in);
        else
            return TransformImpl<I - 1, T>(in);
    }

    std::tuple<const TRANSFORMERS...> transformers;
};


//Example usage

VariadicTransformer<MyTransformer, MyTransformer> varTrans;
MyPoint myPoint;
NotMyPoint notMyPoint;

std::cout << myPoint.x << std::endl;
myPoint = varTrans.Transform(myPoint);
std::cout << myPoint.x << std::endl;

std::cout << notMyPoint.x << std::endl;
notMyPoint = varTrans.Transform<NotMyPoint>(notMyPoint);
std::cout << notMyPoint.x << std::endl;

return 0;
```

My issue comes in with this line:

```
if constexpr(std::get<I>(transformers).CanTransform<T>())
```

This will not compile and provides the following error:

error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant

note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime

note: see usage of 'this'

The CanTransform function should be a constexpr, std::get<#>(std::tuple) should be a constexpr, so I am unsure what its complaint about this line is.

Also the if constexpr is required to avoid trying to call any transformers which are not eligible to transform the current type, I want this case to fall through and return the original.

Any advice on what is causing this error or another design I could try?

Comment: `std::get<I>(this->transformers).CanTransform<T>()` → `std::get<I>(this->transformers).template CanTransform<T>()`

Comment: `return constexpr(...);` isn't valid C++.

Comment: @chris Is it a Visual C++ extension or a bug? I can't find any information on such construction quickly.

Comment: @Constructor, I haven't come across anything of the sort except for a `constexpr` operator in a proposal.

Comment: @chris I had added that out of desperation earlier, it didn't help/hurt but removed it now

Comment: @Constructor .template CanTransform<T>() results in the same error

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Barry There is a more filled out example

Comment: Just make `CanTransform` static. It does not access any members, so there's no reason it needs to be non-static. And if it's static, it no longer requires a `*this` object that is `constexpr`.

Comment: @oisyn You got me on the right track with your comment. I was able to mark the can transform function `static constexpr` inside the base class and that helped, but I was still getting the compiler error about *this.The final resolution was to ALSO use the `tuple_element` call in order to get the type of the element, then call the static function. Trying to call the static function off an instance in the tuple still caused the error with `*this`. So I think this is a good final resolution!

Answer (score 3):

A method call on an object will only be `constexpr` if the calling object is *also* `constexpr`. If the calling object is not `constexpr`, then the method will still be evaluated at runtime instead of compiletime, and thus be ineligible for any compiletime evaluation.

```
struct A {
    int val;
    constexpr A() : A(16) {}
    constexpr A(int val) : val(val) {}
    constexpr bool foo() const {return val > 15;}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    if constexpr(a.foo()) {
        std::cout << "No point thinking about it; this won't compile!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Again, the previous line doesn't compile." << std::endl;
    }

    constexpr A b;
    if constexpr(b.foo()) {
        std::cout << "This, however, will compile, and this message will be displayed!" << std::endl;
    }

    constexpr A c(13);
    if constexpr(c.foo()) {
        std::cout << "This will not be displayed because the function will evaluate to false, but it will compile!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You need to make sure that `TransformImpl` can be made `constexpr`, and then ensure that the instance of `A` which calls `TransformImpl` is also `constexpr`.

Comment: `a.foo()` does compile for me, but `b.foo()` doesn't, because foo needs to be declared `foo() const`, since b is a const and the call to foo() is not allowed then.

Comment: Oh, simply non-`constexpr` class members can't take place in the `constexpr if` condition.

Comment: @Xirema I went through and made everything a constexpr that I could, the compiler is still complaining that access to 'this' makes it non const. The one way I did find around this was to make the tuple as 'static constexpr' but that is less than ideal. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So I can't explain why the previous option wouldn't work. However, but by making the CanTransform function into its own standalone function the error went away.

This finally works:

```
template<typename X, typename T>
constexpr inline bool CanTransform()
{
    return std::is_base_of<ITransform<T>, X>::value;
}

template <class... TRANSFORMERS>
struct VariadicTransformer
{
    constexpr VariadicTransformer() = default;

    template <typename T>
    constexpr inline T Transform(const T& in) const
    {
        return TransformImpl<sizeof...(TRANSFORMERS)-1, T>(in);
    }

private:
        // last attempt to find matching transformer at I==0, if it fails return the original value
    template<std::size_t I = 0, typename T>
    constexpr inline typename std::enable_if<I == 0, T>::type TransformImpl(const T &in) const
    {
        if constexpr(CanTransform < std::tuple_element < I, std::tuple<TRANSFORMERS...>>::type, T >())
            return std::get<I>(transformers).InTransform(in);
        else
            return in;
    }

       // attempt to find transformer for this type
    template<std::size_t I = 0, typename T>
    constexpr inline typename std::enable_if < I != 0, T>::type TransformImpl(const T &in) const
    {
        if constexpr(CanTransform < std::tuple_element < I, std::tuple<TRANSFORMERS...>>::type, T >())
            return std::get<I>(transformers).InTransform(in);
        else
            return TransformImpl<I - 1, T>(in);
    }

    std::tuple<TRANSFORMERS...> transformers;
};
```

Comment: It worked because you made the function `constexpr`.